# Contourf using 'projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()'

Tags: cartopy, contourf

I'm going to draw a map focusing on the Antarctic, the code as follows:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0],projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo())
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -40], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.contourf(lon,lat,ncp,levels=np.linspace(0,60,51),\
            extend='max',cmap = cmaps.WhiteBlueGreenYellowRed,\
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),transform_first=True)
...

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)
ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)
```

It gives the figure on the left, which is weird. How can I get the right one?
[image]

Also, how can I fill the iceshelf places as gray too?

Comment: The weird contours look like an instance of [this issue](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/2233).  You should be able to make features gray by passing `facecolor='gray'` to whatever function you used to add them.

Comment: @RuthC I can understand the problem of weird contours. But you seemed misunderstand my second question. The left panel is drew by Cartopy, you can see clearly in the Ross Sea region the area of iceshelf is not marked as 'continent'. This area is covered by iceshelf and should not have satellite data, I want it to be marked as 'continent' like the right panel shows. Is there any kwards I can add in `cartopy.feature` to achieve that?